# Quad combination time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, dynamic-programming

I came across this problem: Given an array of numbers arr and a number S, find 4 different numbers in arr that sum up to S.

Where the solution is:

```
function findArrayQuadCombination(arr, S):
   if (arr == null OR S == null):
      return null
   n = length(arr)
   if (n < 4):
      return null
   # hashing implementation language dependent:
   pairHash = new HashTable()
   for i from 0 to n-1
      for j from i+1 to n-1
         if !pairHash.isMapped(arr[i]+arr[j]):
            pairHash.map(arr[i]+arr[j], [])
         pairHash.get(arr[i]+arr[j]).push([i, j])

   for pairSum in pairHash.getKeys()
      if pairHash.isMapped(S - pairSum):
         pairsA = pairHash.get(pairSum)
         pairsB = pairHash.get(S - pairsSum)
         combination = find4Uniques(pairsA, pairsB)
         if (combination != null):
            return combination
   return null

# Helper function.
# Gets 2 arrays of sub-arrays of 2 numbers
# Gets 4 unique numbers, from 2 sub-arrays of different arrays
function find4Uniques(A, B):
   lenA = length(A)
   lenB = length(B)
   for i from 0 to lenA-1:
      for j from 0 to lenB-1:
         if ( A[i][0] == B[j][0] OR A[i][1] == B[j][1] OR
              A[i][0] == B[j][1] OR A[i][1] == B[j][0] ):
            continue
         else:
            return [A[i][0], A[i][1], B[j][0], B[j][1]]
   return null
```

The solution says that it is O(n^2), but I disagree.

lenA and lenB in find4Uniques can be at most n^2 in length so find4Uniques is O(n^4)
The "for pairSum in pairHash.getKeys()" line is O(n^2) because there can be n^2 different keys. So shouldn't the whole thing be O(n^6)?

Comment: Don't post code as an image, please.

Comment: Oops sorry I fixed it.

Comment: A related interesting problem: find ALL combinations of 4 entries that equal the given sum.

Answer (score 0):

For the complexity to be `O(n^6)`, the lengths you've given would need to be all true at the same time. Also, the early return in the final loop couldn't be triggered, and the lengths would need to be possible given the mathematical constraints of the sum combinations.

The problem is that the lengths are dependant on each other.

If you had `n^2` keys, their values can now only have a length of 1 because every pair would need to sum to a different value.

If the list had a length `n^2`, then all the pairs would sum to a single value, so there's now only 1 key.

If both `lenA` and `lenB` were `n^2`, then you'd get a non-null return from `find4Uniques` for at least one of the combinations, exiting the whole algorithm, so it can't be run `n^2` times as well.

To show the time-complexity, you'd need to give an actual value of `arr` and `S` that give that complexity.

Comment: You gave 2 cases where it's O(n^2). What I actually asked was why is it O(n^2) in general? Maybe somewhere between those 2 edge cases there's an arr which takes more time?

Answer (score 0):

If all values in `arr` are distinct, then `find4Uniques` will return a value within 3 iterations of the inner loop if `B` has size 3+.  That makes all calls to `find4Uniques` bounded above by the sum of the sizes of the arrays that can be passed in for `A`.  Which is the number of pairs of elements in `arr` and is `O(n^2)`.

However if values in `arr` are NOT distinct, then it need not perform well.  In particular if `S = 6` and `arr = [0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 4, 4,..., 4]` then the answer is `null` but for `pairSum == 1` we'll have `O(n^2)` values in `A` that all look like `[0, 1]` meeting `O(n^2)` values in `B` that all look like `[1, 4]` and will do `O(n^4)` work.

However fixing this performance bug can be easily done by just deduping `arr` first.